# Android apps with same signature but different packages

Tags: android, package, signature, android-build, android-signing

I have android application with different builds:

1. com.my.application.dev
2. com.my.application.test
3. com.my.application.release

but they are signed with same signature.
When i try to install on device few builds simultaneously, i get error
"package with this name already exist".
Is it ok? 
Is this correct behavior?

Comment: Using the same signature is not a problem. It is sometime even mandatory (e.g. when a application defines signature level permission)

Comment: Are you sure they actually have different package names? Changing the folder structure in Android Studio doesn't change the APK package name. That's defined in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: Show your app build.gradle

Comment: I am sure, they have different package names.
First i installed dev build than i look at application info, where was said, that app have  com.my.application.dev package.
then i deleted this build and install test build and again go to app info, there were told, that app has  com.my.application.test package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem.
There was a problem with the content provider, builds had different packages but tried to add content providers with the same name

Answer (score 0):

You could use `applicationIdSuffix` which is：

> Application id suffix. It is appended to the "base" application id
>   when calculating the final application id for a variant.

For example:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        }
    }
}
```